# What is the best way to manipulate a css file using a java servlet filter?

Tags: java, css

I need to convert relative image path (inside some css files) to absolute on the fly, using a java servlet filter.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Filter` that intercepts the path to the CSS file. In that filter, load the CSS file and use a regex to match the CSS attribute you need to modify, capture the URL part, and replace it with what you need. Then write the modified CSS file to the servlet's output stream.

Comment: I thought about something like dom manipulation, I'm afraid that regex is too format-sensitive. I need to modify **every** context path

Comment: I was thinking you could use a regex to look for `url('some/file.jpg')` and the different variations of that. You can do the same for import statements. What else is there?

Comment: Actually, I don't recall anything aside url clause. I'll follow your advice, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give the [CSS Parser Project](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) a look...